# How to add wkhtmltopdf as a layer to Lambda function using aws CDK and Go?

Tags: go, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf in my code to generate reports data in my application.Which works well at my local machine.

I need to add a wkhtmltopdf layer to below lambda function to run the same on server.

```
const graphHandler = new lambda.Function(this, "graphqlHandler", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.GO_1_X,
  functionName: `${STAGE}-graphql`,
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(Path.join("..", "bin")),
  handler: "graphql",
  tracing: Tracing.ACTIVE,
  timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
  memorySize: 512,
  vpc: vpc,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnets: vpc.privateSubnets,
  },
  securityGroups: [vpcSecurityGroup],
});
```

Searched various available articles and documents, but couldn't find much with cdk and Go combination. Anyone with answers, who solved the similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { LayerVersion } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
const layerWkHtmlToPdf = LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(this, "wkhtmltopdf",ARN)
```

Add above constant as a layer to lambda function

```
layers: [layerWkHtmlToPdf],
```

Note : This solution is valid if you have wkhtmltopdf layer available within your lambda section of your aws account.If not, then you can create a wkhtmltopdf layer using class LayerVersion